# Is it possible to pass data after initializing the components?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, components, behaviorsubject

I have three components as shown on the image below and use a custom form component in my feature component. However, there is not a direct parent-child relationship between these two components and there is also a form component between them.

I pass data from feature to form using `@Input` propert that has input values inside a config data (let's say "configData") and then pass them to custom component via `@Input` property (let's say "configData.test" for test input) without any problem (I can pass every parameter when initializing the custom component). However, after initialization, when I set a config value that could be passed on initializing, it is not detected by the custom control. I also tried to use setter for that input as shown below and waited to catch the changes on `ngOnChanges` method. I am not sure if it is possible to update that value if there is not a direct parent-child relationship, but I avoid to use a service in the reusable custom component. So, what is the solution? Do I have to BehaviourSubject and pass value via service?

***custom-component.ts:***

```
private _test: string;
@Input() set test(value: string) {
    this._test = value;
};
get test() { return this._test; }


ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
    console.log(this.test);
}
```

Here is the structure of my components:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like the issue might be from using a config and then an @Input(). Is there a reason for the first relationship not using an @Input() as well?

Comment: Sorry, I misexplained, it is also passed in a config via @Input(), meaning that from fist to second and from second to third component, data is passed via @Input(). So, how can I catch the input value after initializing components?

Comment: Inputs should be updated when changes happen to the original value, so inherently it should be passed down. Have you changed the change detection strategy on any of your components, b/c that can effect how updates happen/passed through components.

Comment: Thanks for helps, no there is no detection strategy on any of my components. The issue seems to be related to some points of Moshezauros's answer. I think I can fix by folowing that suggestions. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your configData is an object, and you only update some of its properties - if that is the case, you should be aware that angular will trigger only when that object reference is changed.

If this is indeed the case here, you can overcome it in one of the following ways:

1. recreate the `configData` object everytime you want to change it- `configData = { ...configData, newProp: newPropValue };` Angular will understand this is a new object and update relevant inputs
2. you can add the DoCheck lifecycle hook - this runs every time Angular runs change detection - so be mindful this will trigger **a lot** more times
3. pass input immutable variables instead of a mutable one - instead of passing `configData` as an object, pass the properties on the object
4. Register with an observable which will trigger everytime `configData` changes and then update your component accordingly

Comment: Very useful seuggestions, thanks a lot, voted up. I think option 1 seems to be suitable for me. But I am not sure how I can update the currentProp value by using spreading operator or etc. Could you also add it to your answer?

Comment: On the other hand, for the custom component, I think it would be better also using option 4, but I am not sure how to register with an observale. Could you pls post an example so that I can set the `mat-autocomplete` value (filteredOptions) according to the example on [this page](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples). You may have  a look at the html and ts files of the first example on that page.

Comment: @Fredrick for option 4, you will have to use a service, here is an example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56714969/how-to-activate-rxjs-subscriber-in-one-component-from-another-angular-component

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be very useful. But I am just wondering an issue: In the image above, in order to emit from custom to feature component, do I need to emit to the form component at first? And then do I have to emit from a method in the second component by triggering that method? I meant first component emit a method in the second component and then I emit event from that method to teh third component?

Comment: On the other hand, is that possible to copy the config value inside a config by using spread operator? Or is it used only for adding new element to the array?

Comment: if you do configData = {...configData }, you create a new object with the same props

Comment: What if just update configData.propertyX while keeping the current values e.g. configData.propertyY and configData.propertyZ?

Comment: if you look at what I wrote in option 1 - you get the same object, but `newProp` gets the new value `newPropValue` - even if that property already existed on configData (it gets overriden if you write it the exact same way)