# problems with ngOnChanges when updating an array

Tags: angular, typescript, lifecycle, ngonchanges

I have an array that is getting updated from another component (the update is happening and Strings are getting added into the array I've checked it with a test button) but ngOnChanges wont detect any change. What is wrong with my code?

The change I apply is array.push().

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import {MatAccordion} from '@angular/material/expansion';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  totalPrice = 0;
  constructor() { }
  @Input() Products: Array<String>;

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log(this.Products)
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

}
```

Comment: do you have **ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush** somewhere in this component's parents?

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65228555/is-it-possible-to-pass-data-after-initializing-the-components/65229241#65229241

Comment: this link is about objects this is an array

Comment: and the link dosent mention anything about the strategy u mentioned

Comment: the first comment was by someone else, and the array and object behave the same in this regard

Comment: check this out : https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using incorrect syntax for [`ngOnChanges`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges). Use the following:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   console.log(changes.Products.currentValue);
}
```

Also, note that unless the *reference* to the array changes the above lifecycle hook will not get triggered. If you want the lifecycle hook to be triggered then change the reference each time you push an element to the array. For eg:

.ts

```
myArr = [];

add() {
  this.myArr = [...this.myArr, String(Math.random())];
  console.log(this.myArr)
}
```

.html

```
<button (click)="add()">Add more numbers</button>

<app-cart-component [Products]="myArr"></app-cart-component>
```

Comment: dosent change anything

Comment: just to mention the change that i apply is array.push()

Comment: From where are you applying this array.push()?

Comment: from the parent component that updates this input... anyways i decided to give up on the array and it works! but will be nice to understand how i was suppose to make this work

Comment: I've included some more explanation along with an example, hope it helps!

Comment: so now its like my code expect you're using spread operator instead of arr.push(). is that what makes the diffrence? if so then thank you

Comment: and by the way the syntax i was using for onChanges is not wrong at all it works fine without array

Comment: I'm changing the reference to the array each time and adding a new element. OnChanges will detect it only when reference changes and not individual element of the same reference change.

Comment: it did help but you will have to remove the first part about ngOnChanges synthax for my to approve it since it gives missleading info. thank you!

Comment: As per the docs, that is the recommended way to use it. More info [here](https://dev.to/nickraphael/ngonchanges-best-practice-always-use-simplechanges-always-1feg)

Comment: nos meus testess mudando um objeto dentro do array no componente pai não dispara o ngOnChanges do componente filho